# Delphi Debugger Error on Android 32-bit Platform

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am experiencing the same error when running with debugging on Android 32-bit platform while on 64-bit has no issue. The debugger just stopped and exited but the app was able to open on my device.

Here's the error:

```
Can't open socket: Permission denied.
Exiting.
```

I thought this was within my app codes error but when I tried a new blank multi-device form, I was getting the same error. So, I suspect this issue is not from my code but a Delphi debugger glitch.

Has anyone here experienced the same issue and was able to resolve this. Otherwise, I will take my chances with Embarcadero support.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Many thanks! However, I can't find any documentation on how to do the patching. I am adamant to touch anything in the Embarcadero directories since this is my first time to do some patching.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Perfect! Thank thank you! I was actually confused with .md file. But it is okay now. Problem solved!

Comment: @RemyLebeau can you post your answer here so I can flag it as answered. Thanks.

Comment: I've posted it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IDE has known problems debugging Android apps. Make sure you have the latest patches installed, such as this one:

[Delphi 10.3.3 Android Debugging Patch](https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/b/blog/posts/delphi-10-3-3-android-debugging-patch)

As the page says:

> The patch is available at https://cc.embarcadero.com/item/30904. Full installation instructions are located in the readme.

Comment: Thank you!. The read me file instruction, in my case, is .md extension. It depends on your default reader application.